# Scrapy not producing outputcsv file

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I have created a spider using selenium plus scrapy which shows that it does scrape the things now until yesterday using the same script i was able to write the output to a csv file but now in the afternoon it showed that the scrapy was not recognized command along with python and pip

so i had installed everything from scratch including python and when i tried to run the spider after , the spider runs smooth but does not write in the preferred manner as it used to earlier.

Have been sticking my brains out from 4 hours now but could not figure out a way if any one can help me that would be really appreciated following are the things that you require

i have tried changing the pipelines multiple times

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'mcmastersds'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['grainger.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'grainger.spiders'

LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'





ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'grainger.pipelines.GraingerPipeline': 300,}
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36 OPR/43.0.2442.806'

PROXY_MODE = 0
RETRY_TIMES = 0

SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050'


SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}
```

pipelines.py

```
import csv
import os.path
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose, Join



class GraingerPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        if not os.path.isfile('CONTENT_psysci.csv'):
            self.csvwriter = csv.writer(open('safale.csv', 'a',newline="",encoding='utf8'))
            self.csvwriter.writerow(['url','Title','sellername','travlink','travlink1','rating','Crreview','feature','Description','proddescription','Additonalinfo','details','detailsextended','producttable','stockstatus','newseller','condition','deliverystatus','price','bestsellersrank','mainimage','subimage'])

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.csvwriter.writerow([item['url'],item['title'],item['sellername'],item['travlink'],item['travlink1'],item['rating'],item['Crreview'],item['feature'],item['Description'],item['proddescription'],item['Additonalinfo'],item['details'],item['detailsextended'],item['producttable'],item['stockstatus'],item['newseller'],item['condition'],item['deliverystatus'],item['price'],item['bestsellersrank'],item['mainimage'],item['subimage']])
        return item
```

can you help me in this

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to write the items without doing anything specific to the data, I'd suggest using the [feed exports](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-exports) feature. Scrapy has a builtin [CSV feed exporter](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#csv) provided.

The reason your code isn't working above is because you never close the csv file you open in your `self.csvwriter` initializing statement.

You should use the `open_spider` and `close_spider` methods to open the file and close it after the items are processed, have a look at the [json pipeline example](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-a-json-file) in the scrapy docs which is similar.

Your pipeline above should thus be adapted to the following code:

```
class GraingerPipeline(object):

    csv_file = None

    def open_spider(self):
        if not os.path.isfile('CONTENT_psysci.csv'):
            self.csvfile = open('safale.csv', 'a',newline="",encoding='utf8')
            self.csvwriter = csv.writer(self.csvfile)
            self.csvwriter.writerow(['url','Title','sellername','travlink','travlink1','rating','Crreview','feature','Description','proddescription','Additonalinfo','details','detailsextended','producttable','stockstatus','newseller','condition','deliverystatus','price','bestsellersrank','mainimage','subimage'])

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.csvwriter.writerow([item['url'],item['title'],item['sellername'],item['travlink'],item['travlink1'],item['rating'],item['Crreview'],item['feature'],item['Description'],item['proddescription'],item['Additonalinfo'],item['details'],item['detailsextended'],item['producttable'],item['stockstatus'],item['newseller'],item['condition'],item['deliverystatus'],item['price'],item['bestsellersrank'],item['mainimage'],item['subimage']])
        return item

    def close_spider(self):
        if self.csv_file:
            self.csv_file.close()
```

Comment: Hi ian it still doesnt write or open a csv file

Comment: Have you tried using the CSV feed exporter? Also, does it work if you remove the conditional like - `if not os.path.isfile('CONTENT_psysci.csv'):` - in the `open_spider` method?

Comment: Hi ian i have tried both the ways you suggested but neither works, and i am surprised this happened all of s sudden while it was working previously

Comment: Do the scrapy logs give any indication or error for the pipeline?

Comment: no nothing it just show the crawled data and nothing else